# I **really** need a function defined by user input. What are my options?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm writing a Python script that parses a user-inputted string defining a differential equation, such as `'x\' = 2*x'`. My main problem is that I don't want to implement numerical solution methods myself, and instead rely on [SciPy's solve_ivp method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp), for which a function such as

```
def my_de(t, x):
    return 2*x
```

is absolutely necessary, since solve_ivp's first argument must be a function. Currently, I'm working around this problem with the following piece of code (in a simplified version):

```
var = 'x'
de = '2*x'
def my_de(t, y):
    exec(f'{var} = {y}')
    return eval(de)
```

A quick explanation for this terribleness: I do not know what variable the user's going to use in the input. `var` may be `theta`, it may be `sleepyjoe`, it may be `donalddump`. The only thing guaranteed is that the only variable on `de` is `var`. You can forget about `t` for the purposes of this post.

My question is, how can I avoid using `exec` and `eval` in this context? I know using any of these is a terrible idea, and I don't want to do it. However, I'm not really seeing any other option.

I am already parsing the user input beforehand, so I can try to make this safe (prohibited variable names, etc.), but anyone who wants to abuse this will be able to anyway.

Comment: Is the security issue your question, or is it just that you don’t want the *unstructured* aspect of `exec`/`eval`?  This situation is not one of the standard misuses of those functions where a dictionary would suffice.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I just wanted to know if there is a better solution to this problem, i.e. one where I can avoid using `exec` and `eval`. Security isn't a huge issue in the context of the problem, since the user of the program is the only one who has to deal with the consequences of the code he may write

Comment: Save yourself some headaches and impose some conditions on input.  Parse it, and create a parameterized function.  You certainly don't want to do `eval` each time the function is called by `solve_ivp`.

Comment: @hpaulj The input is already parsed and conditioned, though I still need to improve that portion of the code. I'm not entirely sure what you mean with the rest of your comment. Can you elaborate? Specifically about parameterized functions and `eval`. How would I avoid using it at each function call?

Comment: One way could be to parse the expression via sympy, and then use `sympy.lambdify` to convert it to a numpy function.

Comment: @JohanC This is a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous comments, another possibility is to evaluate the function definition itself:

```py
userInput="2*x + x**3" # the input you wish to implement
exec("""def test(x): return {}""".format(userInput))
print(test(1.))
```

This will avoid the overhead of evaluating the `userInput` at each call.